# How to prevent a user from entering more than 4 digit in year area

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working on JQuery Mobile Datebox and there is something i can't fix. If user type some weird input in year area something like *1988123*, datebox gets crazy and changes value of date "undefined, undefined NaN, NaN".

I tried the get only year value from Datebox, but day, month or year area doesn't have id field. So I couldn't get any solution. Can anybody help me?

Comment: try `maxlength="4"`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: It works if and only if I try to write anything on input field without using datebox. But in my problem, there is a datebox in input field and datebox's date, month and year areas don't have id. Because of no-id situation, I can't use maxlength, but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

try HTML5 pattern:

```
<form
onsubmit="alert('Submitted.');return false;">
    <input
    type="text"
    required=""
    pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))"
    value=""
    name="dates_pattern2"
    id="dates_pattern2"
    list="dates_pattern2_datalist"
    placeholder="Try it out.">
    <input
    type="submit"
    value="»">
    <datalist
    id="dates_pattern2_datalist"></datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it didn't work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did find a solution.
As you know, JQuery Mobile Datebox has some data-options. I find an option which is "maxYear".

```
<input  name="tarih1" id="tarih1"  type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "maxYear":"3000"}' placeholder="GG.AA.YYYY">
```

With this solution, user can't choose a year which has more than 4 digit. (You can change 3000 to another 4 digit year. Bu don't forget, if you choose for example 1999, user can't choose greater than 1999)